# How do I make a list of times 2 with existing list?

Tags: python, list

```
seq=[1,2,3,4,5]
def times2(var):
    return var*2
for number in seq:
    index=seq.index(number)
    seq[index]=times2(number)
```

print(seq)

Why is it showing [8, 2, 6, 4, 10]? I want to see `[2,4,6,8,10]`. I don't want to use map.

Comment: You really should attempt to debug this program. Learning how to debug something like this is crucial, and you aren't going to learn until you start doing it. So start by putting some `print`'s in there, print what `number` is and what `index` is at each step in the loop. Maybe also print `seq` at each step too...

Answer (score 1):

You could use a list comprehension.

```py
seq = [1,2,3,4,5]
print([n * 2 for n in seq])
```

Comment: The question is why their code is failing...

Comment: @MSH true, but I am answering the title of the question, "How do I make a list of times 2 with existing list?"